# Datetime manipulation for a scheduled R Script

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I am trying to subset a dataframe with some datetime manipulation

```
current <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
current$mday <- current$mday
Back6hours <- current
Back3hours <- current
Back6hours$hour <- Back6hours$hour-6
Back3hours$hour <- Back3hours$hour-3
```

This one works fine for all times but the scheduled R Script errors out when the current time is **00:00 AM & 03:00 AM**

I tried manually entering the current time and working around it to figure out the issue but it errors out for any value that is manually given.

```
current <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
current$mday <- current$mday
current$hour = "6"
current$min = "30"
current$sec = "0"
Back6hours <- current
Back3hours <- current
Back6hours$hour <- Back6hours$hour-6
Back3hours$hour <- Back3hours$hour-3
```

"**Error in Back6hours$hour - 6 : non-numeric argument to binary operator**"

How can I work around this error? I would like to schedule this R script to run every 3 hours in a day but this logic seems to error out at 12 AM & 3 AM. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Errors that occur with 2 or 3 AM are typical for problems with daylight savings times shifts. But in this case you need to look at the value of `Back6hours$hour` which is NOT numeric. I see this error as essentially a typo. All you need to do is use `as.numeric`.

Comment: This gives the current time, 3 hours ago, 6 hours ago, ..., 21 hours ago: `seq(Sys.time(), by = "-3 hours", length = 8)`